# Where is SQL Profiler in my SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler, profiling

I downloaded [SQL Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2008) and can't seem to find [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173918%28SQL.80,printer%29.aspx) anywhere.

I believe I installed the SQL Server Enterprise Express/trial version?

I guess it was Express and not Enterprise after all right?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

SQL Server Express does not come with profiler, but you can use [SQL Server 2005/2008 Express Profiler](http://sqlprofiler.googlepages.com/) instead.

Comment: I was looking this. its cool that it is free. :) How can I save trace data to text file? File/Save button is disabled

Comment: DataWizard is now only free as time-limited trial, but licences start at just $5 USD for a year for up to 3 servers.Don't be put off by the problems with the DataWizard website (it often takes you round in circles) - the software itself is excellent and I'm assured by Joe at DataWizard.com they are working on improving the website... (fingers crossed!)

Comment: It is no longer available from that download link.

Answer (score 24):

first get the profiler Exe from: http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com

then you can add it simply to the Management studio:

Tools -> External tools... ->

a- locate the exe file on your disk (If installed, it's typically C:\Program Files (x86)\ExpressProfiler\ExpressProfiler.exe)

b- give it a name e.g. Express Profiler

that's it :)
you have your Profiler with your sql express edition

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Another very basic free profiler:
http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com

Answer (score 3):

Management Studio->Tools->SQL Server Profiler.

If it is not installed see [this link](http://vijayvepa.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/installing-sql-server-2008-r2-profiler/)

Comment: In what SKU? I have 2008 R2 management studio installed and don't have a profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Also ensure that "client tools" are selected in the install options. However if SQL Managment Studio 2008 exists then it is likely that you installed the express edition.